# Why is pytorch running out of memory on a trivial multiplication?

Tags: pytorch, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get the [pytorch MNIST tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html) to run using WSL2/Ubuntu and RTX 3060 Ti GPU.  On the first training batch it slurps up all the linux RAM until Ubuntu kills it.

After paring down the tutorial, I see the same failure with tiny tensors in this simple repro case.

```
import torch
x0 = torch.tensor([[1.], [4.]], device='cuda')
w0 = torch.tensor([[2.]], device='cuda')
y0 = torch.nn.functional.linear(x0, w0)    <-- crashes here, should return tensor([[2.], [8.]])
```

[jupyter kernel runs out of memory and dies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27sfK.png)

What I've tried:

1. Checking that the GPU can be seen from the shell and pytorch.cuda.is_available() == True
2. Creating the tensors locally rather than on the cuda device - this works.
3. Running the code through python command line rather than jupyter - fails.
4. Various NVIDIA windows drivers for cuda versions 11.4 to 12.0 - doesn't seem to matter.
5. Wiping and rebuilding the WSL Ubuntu instance - doesn't help.

```
$ conda list | grep torch
pytorch                   1.13.1          py3.10_cuda11.7_cudnn8.5.0_0
pytorch-cuda              11.7                 h67b0de4_1

$ nvidia-smi
Wed Feb 15 15:27:25 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.75       Driver Version: 517.40       CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P8    12W / 200W |    515MiB /  8192MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

ls -al /usr/lib/wsl/lib
total 74192
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root       40 Feb 15 15:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Feb 15 06:13 ..
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   141464 Sep 12 16:54 libcuda.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   141464 Sep 12 16:54 libcuda.so.1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   141464 Sep 12 16:54 libcuda.so.1.1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   800568 Oct  7 18:46 libd3d12.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  6224608 Oct  7 18:46 libd3d12core.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   829248 Oct  7 18:46 libdxcore.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  5950624 Sep 12 16:54 libnvcuvid.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  5950624 Sep 12 16:54 libnvcuvid.so.1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  7547400 Sep 12 16:54 libnvdxdlkernels.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   424400 Sep 12 16:54 libnvidia-encode.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   424400 Sep 12 16:54 libnvidia-encode.so.1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   212624 Sep 12 16:54 libnvidia-ml.so.1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   354768 Sep 12 16:54 libnvidia-opticalflow.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   354768 Sep 12 16:54 libnvidia-opticalflow.so.1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 45845584 Sep 12 16:54 libnvwgf2umx.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   600472 Sep 12 16:54 nvidia-smi
```

Comment: It worked well by google colab with both cpu and gpu.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 or 11?  Also, which `wsl --version` are you on?  (Could return an error if the version is too early).  Thanks!

Comment: I ran wsl --update before my little adventure.  It claims to be 1.0.3.0.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working by making sure WSL is configured with more memory than the GPU. It seems NVIDIA's Unified Virtual Addressing (UVA) wants to map the RTX 3060 Ti's whole 8GB into linux's memory space on the first call? When I increased my WSL memory from 2GB to 16GB (via %USERPROFILE%\.wslconfig), my example and the pytorch tutorial started working.